# Merge two files line by line with the delimiter triple pipe symbol "|||"

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have two parallel files with the same number of lines in two languages and plan to merge these two files line by line with the delimiter `|||`. E.g., the two files are as follows:

File A:

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you.
1Mo 1,2 I like you.
Hi 1,3 I am hungry.
Hi 1,4 I am foolish.
```

File B:

```
1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
Hi 1,3 Ich habe Durst.
Hi 1,4 Ich bin neu.
```

The expected output is like this:

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you. ||| 1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 I like you. ||| 1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
Hi 1,3 I am hungry. ||| Hi 1,3 Ich habe Durst.
Hi 1,4 I am foolish. ||| Hi 1,4 Ich bin neu.
```

I tried the `paste` command such as:

```
paste -d "|||" fileA fileB
```

But the returned output is only containing one pipe such as:

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you. |1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 I like you. |1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
```

Is there any way to separate each pair of lines by tripe pipe `|||`?

Comment: `paste -d '|||' fileA - - fileB < /dev/null`

Comment: offtopic, but your translations are not correct ;) "Ich habe Durst" = I am thisrty, "Ich bin neu" = I am new ... does not necessarily mean that you are foolish.
...just in case you are actually learning German...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thx, but my output is still only containing one pipe...

Comment: @dave_alcarin Dank sehr!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With [POSIX paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
:|paste -d ' ||| ' fileA - - - - fileB
```

`paste` will concatenate corresponding lines of all input files. Here we have six files, `fileA`,  four dummy files from standard in `-`, and `fileB`.

The list of delimiters include a space, three pipe and a space in that order will be used by `paste` circularly.

For the first line of six files, `fileA` will be concatenated with the first  dummy file (which is nothing, thank to the [no-op :](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16) operator), produce `line1-fileA<space>`.

The first dummy file will be concatenated with the second by a pipe, produce `line1-fileA |`, then the second dummy file with the third dummy file, produce `line1-fileA ||`, the third dummy file with the the forth dummy file, produce `line1-fileA |||`.

And the forth dummy file with `fileB`, produce `line1-fileA ||| line1-fileB`.

Those step will be repeated for all lines, give you the expected result.

---

The use of `:|` is for less-typing, and mainly use in interactive shell. In a script, you should use:

```
</dev/null paste -d ' ||| ' fileA - - - - fileB
```

to prevent a subshell from being spawned.

Comment: +1 for the `:|`.  clever alternative to `</dev/null`

Comment: ...and +1 for the smart use of 4 dummy files from standard input with `- - - -`, but next time you can even write a couple of lines for explanation  :)

Comment: Thx, but I still get the output with one pipe...

Comment: @hui, did you run the command exactly as given including all the dashes and space characters? What's your operating system?

Comment: `:|paste -d '|' fileA - - fileB` gives the more correct version without the space delimiter.

Comment: @Hastur: Add more details explanation. I don't have time to explain at the time when I posted the answer.

Comment: @PålGD Why do you assert that it is more correct without spaces? In the OP _expected output_ there are, in the OP input files there are not. So it was proper to add.  ||| To cuongin : It's a pity I cannot vote for this answer again. |||

Comment: @PålGD: If the lines contain trailing space, then you only need `|||`, but in the OP's question, they do not.

Comment: @PålGD I disagree the firmness of your assertion(s), and I like the strength of your belief. :-)  Indeed I admit the OP should be more clear. He asserts _desired output_ with `_|||_` (with spaces) and that he tried `|||` (without) obtaining only one `|`... then asked how to separate with three. BTW the focus of the question is on the `|||` symbols and not on the spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Now it works. Sorry for the last comment.

Comment: @cuonglm Now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PålGD: It worked for the OP now.

Comment: @PålGD You're right. And it has not to be (the space). Maybe he writes those lines by hands, or he added the space by hands to evidence the `|` symbol... hmm... (some second later) Tested: you're right even on the 2 systems on which I just tried. It should be not.

Answer (score 7):

Well, this doesn't use sed, awk, or grep, but you can do it pretty easily in bash.  The command is:

```
(while IFS= read -r a <&3 && IFS= read -r b <&4; do echo "$a ||| $b"; done) 3<fileA 4<fileB
```

The problem with paste is that the delimiter is a single character.  You could also insert a single character and the use sed to transform it, but that would be kind of error-prone if the character already appeared in the input file.

Comment: Your solution won't work if line contain any backslash character, or start with dash. You want to use `IFS=` before each `read`. You can easily do it with `paste`. See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244890/38906), and also [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906) to see why should avoid using `while` loop in shell script.

Comment: It works for my file. Many Thx!!!

Answer (score 5):

An awk (GNU) version

```
awk '{printf ("%s ||| ", $0); getline < "fileB"; print $0 }' fileA
```

With the `getline` command in `awk`, you can set `$0` (all variables for columns) from next input record, if `getline < "filename"` you set the next `$0` from the specified file.

> getline < "file"         Set $0 from next record of file; set NF.

---

Why your attempt didn't work as you expect? From `man paste` we can read

```
-d, --delimiters=LIST
     reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs
```

but **it uses the delimiters one for each column**.

So  the command
`paste -d '|*|*' fileA fileB fileA fileB` gives me lines as

> `Hi 1,3 I am hungry.|Hi 1,3 Ich habe Durst.*Hi 1,3 I am hungry.|Hi 1,3 Ich...`
>    `Hi 1,4 I am foolish.|Hi 1,4 Ich bin neu.*Hi 1,4 I am foolish.|Hi 1,4 Ich...`

---

A `sed` solution that  I suggest to avoid even if close to your original attempt, because it patches the obtained behaviour to your original purpose:

```
 paste -d '|' fileA fileB | sed 's/|/|||/g'
```

To avoid because you substitute each pattern `|` with the new one `|||`, **but you have to assume that the pipe symbol (`|`) is not present in your data**, else you have to deal with special cases and make a more complex the code to avoid side effects.

---

A variant with the *Here String* [[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)] construct `<<<`

```
 paste -d ' ||| ' fileA - - - - fileB  <<< ''
```

You set 5 delimiters with `-d ' ||| '` (space,|,|,|,space) and  4 dummy files (`- - - -`) that will take data from the empty string `''`.

---

<sub>Tested on GNU Awk 4.0.1,  paste (GNU coreutils) 8.21 and sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2</sub>

Comment: Thx,  the awk command works!

Comment: UR welcome. Updated the answer adding a `sed` example to avoid ( :-) ) and more comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid the magic and drama of circular delimiters and
dummy files, you could just append your delimiter to one file before
pasting them:

```
paste <(sed 's/$/ |||/' filea) fileb
```

gives

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you. ||| 1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 I like you. ||| 1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
Hi 1,3 I am hungry. ||| Hi 1,3 Ich habe Durst.
Hi 1,4 I am foolish. |||    Hi 1,4 Ich bin neu.
```

Comment: I like this for simplicity.  I believe you mean "prepend", not "append" though.  Checkout Hastur's awk answer for the awk version of this.

Comment: You should change the process substitution to a pipe, so you won't have the limit for number of shells support it.

Comment: @Wildcard yes, prepend, but I'll rewrite it to append to filea. I think awk is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: @cuonglm true, but I wanted to avoid pipes for clarity. I felt a pipe would make it start to look like the dummy files, but you are correct

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in python too in this way.

```
lines1 = [ line.rstrip() for line in open("file1") ]
lines2 = [ line.rstrip() for line in open("file2") ]
for i in xrange((len(lines1))): print lines1[i] + " ||| " + lines2[i]
... 
1Mo 1,1 I love you. ||| 1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 I like you. ||| 1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
Hi 1,3 I am hungry. ||| Hi 1,3 Ich habe Durst.
Hi 1,4 I am foolish. ||| Hi 1,4 Ich bin neu.
```